# When an item is created in "list a", the item is automatically created in "list B"

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have two lists in my SharePoint site:

- Employee database (name, address etc.)
- Competence registration (skills, experience etc.)

What I want to do, is when I create a new employee in my "Employee database list", the name of the newly created employee is automatically created in my other list "Competence registration". And when I delete an employee from my "Employee database list", the employee is automatically deleted from the "competence registration" list.

How can I do that?

Comment: you can get much help of this link https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-list-relationships-by-using-unique-and-lookup-columns-80a3e0a6-8016-41fb-ad09-8bf16d490632

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one approach is to use event receivers to implement this functionality :
 When itemadded() eventreceivers is triggered , you can write the business logic to insert into the second splist.

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    //base.Itemadded(properties);


    SPUser currUser = properties.Web.CurrentUser;

    this.EventFiringEnabled = false;

    try
    {

        // if (properties.ListTitle.ToLower() == NPDListNames.ITEMLEVELPERMISSIONSLIST.ToString())
        // {

        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {

            SPSite CurrentSite = new SPSite(properties.SiteId);
            SPWeb CurrentWeb = CurrentSite.OpenWeb(properties.RelativeWebUrl);

            SPList CurrentList = CurrentWeb.Lists[properties.ListId];

            SPListItem CurrentListItem;
            CurrentListItem = 
     CurrentWeb.Lists[properties.ListId].
   GetItemById(properties.ListItem.ID);

  // fetch the other list using the elevatedweb and insert a new item into //the second list .
```

Answer (score 1):

For this requirement, you will have to create a Sharepoint designer list workflow on Employee database list.
For information on how to create a workflow, follow this link - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj554671.aspx

Create this workflow for **item created**.
Open this workflow in edit mode and on the Ribbon, click on **Actions**, find **Create List Item.**
[image]

You will see this syntax appear on the editor- **Create item in *this list* (Output to Variable: create )**
Click on ***this list***, Select the list you want to create item in (Competence registration in your case), and click on ADD to add your columns and its values.

[image]

The dropdown **set this field** shows the list of all the columns in the list Competence registration. Select your column and click **fx** to add your value.
Select **Current Item** (which is the list Employee database) and **Field from this Source** will display all the columns from this list. Choose your field and click on **OK**.

[image]

In the last step, after *Go to* select ***End of workflow***.

[image]

Click on **Save** and **Check For Errors** in the Ribbon. If there are no Errors, click on **Publish** and you are set to go with your 'on created workflow'.

Unfortunately, for 'on deleted', there is no such thing you can do.
Workflows always fire after the event that causes them. Since the workflow
needs the context of the object to run in and the document is gone once its
deleted you can't attach a workflow  to the deletion of a document. You can
write event handlers in Visual Studio that will fire when a user asks that a
document be deleted, but not a workflow.